# PostgreSQL performance on joins using integer[] columns vs. link table

Tags: arrays, postgresql, performance, join

We have a table `user_info` with high read-write-update activity containing millions of rows and another table `combinations` with low write, high read containing thousands of rows. We need to link these two tables on a unique ID in `combinations` composed of 3 integers using a one-many relationship. Each row in `user_info` will be linked to ~5 rows in `combinations`.

**Example combinations:**

```
id, some_id1, some_id2, some_id3
1, 10, 10, 100
2, 10, 21, 201
3, 20, 21, 201
```

**Example user_info (with array column approach):**

```
id, some_column_1, some_column_2, combination_ids
1, 'Bla bla', 'Smth', {1,3}
2, 'Bla bla', 'Smth Smth', {2,3}
```

We know that this could be done both using an integer[] column on `user_info` or using a link table. We are interested in optimizing for performance, specifically for joins between the two tables involving many rows. All the tables would be indexed on the relevant columns. Would it be faster to join using array columns or using a link table?

Comment: I am confident that the solution without an array would be faster. [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Why would you think so?